# Asymmertric Wheel Valve Stem Hole Placement

Tags: wheels

I have just purchased a new bike. It came with Fulcrum Racing 700 Disc Centrelock Wheelset. I noticed the valve stem hole machined into the rim is off centre. I queried this with the technical desk of the company I purchased the bike from and was told that it was correct. Apparently, due to the asymmetric construction of the wheel it is produced that way to add more material on one side of the rim and thus increase its strength. Your thoughts/comments/is this BS or is it correct?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's normal, a quick google gets many hits dating back several models/years

It's mentioned in this review:

https://road.cc/content/review/234000-fulcrum-racing-5-disc-brake-wheelset